# JSDoc for function parameter properties + WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc, jsdoc3

What is the correct JSDdoc declaration for `company` being a String in the code below?

```js
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/mdo').then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
  console.log(res.company);
});
```

I use WebStorm and it understandably underscores `company` as an `Unresolved variable`:

[image: WebStorm underscored property as Unresolved variable]

if I add

```
/** @namespace bogus.company **/
```

anywhere in the file, WebStorm is happy, but that doesn't make sense:

[image: WebStorm happy with bogus declaration]

Is this a bug in WebStorm, or am I missing something about how JSDoc declarations are supposed to work?

Is JSDoc even supposed to be used for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the inspection for `unresolved javascript variable` there is a `Report undeclared properties as error` option that you could uncheck.

I like to do something like this:

```
/**
 * @param {Object} res
 * @property {String} company
 */
function myOutput(res) {
  console.log(res.company);
}

fetch('https://api.github.com/users/mdo')
  .then(myToJson)
  .then(myOutput);
```

But for small anonymous functions I wouldn't even bother. It's a weak warning so turn the inspection off or learn to live with it, I'd say. It's possible to cram in `/** @param {*} something */` in anonymous functions as well, but often it only serves to reduce readability.

Another option is to make a dummy file `soomething.js` somewhere under your content-root with an anonymous function like:

```
(() => {
  return {
    "github-users-response" : {
      "company" : "sample"
    }
  }
});
```

And now webstorm will figure that company actually *is* defined in your other files. You can even put it in a different content-root if you want to keep it separate from your project.